# Grouping a View by Custom Field

Tags: views

Hi there i hope you can help. Drupal info below.

Core module :   6.22
Installed modules: CCK, Views, Image, SEO.

I have a custom field called field_type which i need to group by.

After searching in vain on the internet for a long time I'm unable to find an answer that works.

Could anyone give me step by step instructions how to create a view like the sketch below.
Basically each item has a type assigned to it, and i need to group the results of the view by type. Preferably with a title above the group to say which type it is.

Type 1 -

Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4

Type 2 -

Item 5, Item 6, Item 7, Item 8

Type 3 -

Item 9, Item 10, Item 11, Item 12

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell....

Create a view, with a filter of the node type that contains this field_type and if it's published etc.

Add all the fields you want to display, including the field_type.

In Advanced Settings, turn grouping on.

In Style Settings, click on the Unformatted Settings (the round dodad next to Unformatted :) and in there you will now see a grouping field...so select field_type.

Save and preview.  It should do what you want data wise, so just add whatever CSS is needed to make it look pretty.